# Dekker's algorithm for 3 processes

Tags: algorithm, concurrency

As my asignment I have to verify something on Dekker's algorithm - but with 3 processes -

I can only find original version for 2 processes.

The goal is not the algorithm but it's implementation and verification in SMV System
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~modelcheck/smv.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably ask the course staff, but you can use two Dekker mutexes to achieve three-process mutex. Processes 0 and 1 compete to acquire mutex A; the holder of mutex A and process 2 compete to acquire mutex B, whose holder is allowed to run a critical section.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // Dekkers algorithm version3
  system:
  boolean t1WantsToEnter=false;
  boolean t2WantsToEnter=false;
  startThreads;//initialize and launch all threads

  Thread T1;
  void main();{
  while(!done);
  {
  t1WantsToEnter=true;
  while(t2WantsToEnter); //wait
  //critical section cokde
  t1WantsToEnter=false;
  //code outside critical section

  Thread T2;
  void main();{
  while(!done);
  {
  t2WantsToEnter=true;
  while(t1WantsToEter);//wait
  //critical section code
  t2WantsToEnter=false;
  //code outside critical section
  // if u want to know how this code is executed using RAM diagram,
```

Comment: isn't this answer a duplicate of the one above?

Answer (score -1):

```c
// Dekkers algorithm version3
system:
    boolean t1WantsToEnter = false;
    boolean t2WantsToEnter = false;
    startThreads; // initialize and launch all threads

// Thread T1
void main() {
    while(!done);
    {
        t1WantsToEnter = true;
        while(t2WantsToEnter) { // wait
            // critical section cokde
            t1WantsToEnter = false;
        }
        // code outside critical section
    } // end outer while
} // end Thread T1

// Thread T2
void main() {
    while(!done);
    {
        t2WantsToEnter = true;
        while (t1WantsToEter) { //wait
            // critical section code
            t2WantsToEnter =false;
        }
        // code outside critical section
    } // end outer while
} // end Thread T2
```